# In an set of integers, find three elements summing to zero (3-sum, leetcode variant)

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, programming-challenge, k-sum

I use a dummy solution to solve the leetcode [3Sum](https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/description/) problem.

I employ the *set* data type to handle duplicates, then transform back to list.

> Given an array `nums` of *n* integers, are there elements *a*, *b*, *c*  in `nums` such that *a* + *b* + *c* = 0?  Find all unique triplets in the array which gives the sum of zero.
>
> **Note:**
>
> The solution set must not contain duplicate triplets.
>
> **Example:**
>
> Given array `nums = [-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -4]`,
>
> A solution set is:
>
> ```
> [
>   [-1, 0, 1],
>   [-1, -1, 2]
> ]
> ```

My codes:

```
from typing import List
import logging
import unittest
import random
from collections import defaultdict,Counter

##logging.disable(level=#logging.CRITICAL)
##logging.basicConfig(level=#logging.DEBUG, format="%(levelname)s %(message)s")

    class Solution:
        def threeSum(self, nums, target: int=0) -> List[List[int]]:
            """
            :type nums: List[int]
            :type target: int 
            """
            if len(nums) < 3: return []

            triplets = []
            if target == [0, 0, 0]: 
                triplets.append([0, 0, 0])
                return triplets # finish fast 

            lookup = {nums[i]:i for i in range(len(nums))} #overwrite from the high
            if len(lookup) == 1:#assert one identical element 
                keys = [k for k in lookup.keys()]
                if keys[0] != 0: 
                    return []
                else:
                    triplets.append([0,0,0])
                    return triplets



            triplets_set = set()

            for i in range(len(nums)):
                num_1 = nums[i]
                sub_target = target - num_1
                # #logging.debug(f"level_1_lookup: {lookup}")

                for j in range(i+1, len(nums)):
                    num_2 = nums[j]
                    num_3 = sub_target - num_2              
                    k = lookup.get(num_3) #             
                    if k not in {None, i, j}: #don't reproduce itself  
                        result = [num_1, num_2, num_3]
                        result.sort()
                        result = tuple(result)
                        triplets_set.add(result)

            triplets = [list(t) for t in triplets_set]
            return triplets
```

My solution gets this result:

> Your runtime beats 28.86 % of python3 submissions.

Could anyone please give hints to improve?

Comment: Can you check the problem description? It is about pairs (a, b) which sum to 9, but the examples are about triples which sum to zero. – Btw, if you beat 28.86 of other submissions then you are slower 71.14 percent, not slower than 80 percent :)

Comment: As *set* is a common verb in English, try to avoid confusion: *set* is a Python [built-in *data* type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset). (Grant me the favour and never call any amount of program source code ["codes"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_(disambiguation)#Computing).) How could `target: int` `== [0, 0, 0]`?

Comment: amazing, better than leetcode's big data testing. @greybeard

Comment: Ah, before I forget *again*: Congrats on asking for a review, for `hints to improve` instead of a turn-key solution, on (seemingly) trying to come up with a solution of your own instead of scraping the web/SE/leetcode. Way to learn!

Answer (score 3):

Multi-part answer: [0) these preliminaries] 1) review of code presented 2) hints for improvement excluding *personal*, from *programming* over *python* and *accepting a programming challenge* to *k-sum* and *leetcode 3Sum*.

One general principle to follow is *do as expected*, in programming, it has been formulated in many guises, including [Principle of Least Surprise](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment#Formulation). Every other route leaves you under pressure to justify, at risk of being misunderstood.

In coding, *document, in the program source code*:
What is "everything" there for?

Such rules often have been gathered into *guide lines*, for Python, follow the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#contents).

---

- Instead of a [docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring), your module starts with imports - most of them unused.
- *If your code* mentioned *leetcode*, the presentation of a `class Solution` with just one function definition wouldn't beg justification.
- the definition of `threeSum()` shows (a cute addition of `target`&default and) a curious mix of leetcode's templates for Python 2&3, lacking a proper docstring
- comparing "the int" `target` to the list literal `[0, 0, 0]` is dangerous given Python's zeal to allow operations: do you know by heart when that evaluates to `True`?
  (Do you expect most every reader of your code to?)
  (Belatedly, it occurred to me that you may have intended to compare `nums` to `[0, 0, 0]` - bogus if `target != 0`)
- verbosity - 
  you can denote a tuple containing a single literal list like `([v, v, v],)`
- 2nd early out:
  with only one key→value in the *dict*, there's no need to access it:
  *every* key will equal `nums[0]`
  You need to check for `3*nums[0] != target`
- naming (Not your fault: `Solution` and `threeSum` are substandard.
  `nums`/_1-3 don't *feel* bad enough to change):
  - `target`, `triplets`, `sub_target`: right on!
  - given Python's "duck typing", I'd stick with `triplets` (, never introducing `triplets_set`)
  - `lookup` is a horrible name → `value_to_index` (or, in a suitably small context, just `index`)
  (- there's one thing wrong with `k`: it gets in the way when extending three_sum() to k_sum()…)
- *pythonic* or not (or exploiting library functions, rather?):
  `value_to_index = { value: index for index, value in enumerate(nums) }`
  (same for `for i, num_1 in enumerate(nums)`, `for j, num_2 in enumerate(nums[i+1:], i+1)`)
- commenting
  - you *did* comment, and I find half of the comments helpful
  - I don't get `#overwrite from the high` (that *may* just be me)
  - `#don't reproduce itself`: probably `use any element/index once, at most` rather than `don't repeat an element/index`
  - you did *not* comment the outer for loop, arguably the most profitable place:
  *how* is what the execution constructs a *solution*?:
  for each value, `value_to_index` keeps just the last index: how does this *not* prevent any valid triple to show up in the solution?
- checking `k`: *nice*!
  (I'd go for `in (None, i, j)`)
- you don't provide a "tinker harness"

  ```
  if __name__ == '__main__':
      object_disoriented = Solution()
      print(object_disoriented.threeSum([-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -4]))
      print(object_disoriented.threeSum([1, 1, 1], 3))
  ```

---

(Something else to follow is *make (judicious) use of every help you can*: if you use an IDE supporting Python, chances are it can help you with PEP8.)
(Running low on steam, this part will start more frugal than expected.)

*Real Programming* is the creation of a language that simplifies the solution of the problem at hand.

With Python providing most *mechanisms* needed in programming challenges, that leaves:

- Code readably.
- Create elements easy to use correctly.

I bickered you some about *having a consistent problem description*.
This is another place where [Test First](http://pythontesting.net/agile/test-first-programming/) shines:
As long as you find yourself not knowing what to test, you are not in a position to implement anything, yet. (Inconsistencies in specification tend to stand out in test design & implementation.)

*Programming challenges* à la leetcode.com typically build on simpler challenges - you met 2sum, which puts you in a favourable position to tackle 3sum.
The performance part of these challenges is about not doing things over, not discarding knowledge more often than about algebraic insight.

The generic solution to 2sum is to take values and *find the complement* (1sum?).
The extension to *k*-sum is to split *k* into smaller numbers.

Ways to have information about the order of a set or sequence (say, *elements*) of instances of a type with ordering reusable is to have them ordered (`ordered = sorted(elements)`) or sorted (`histogram = Counter(elements)`).
For 2sum, you could search for `target/2` and work inside-out.
For 3sum, one value will be no greater, another no smaller than both others. The third one will not "lie outside" the former two.